# Android Logcat message:

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have a simple Fragment Android project. I have 2 fragments off the the Main Activity. I keep getting these messages in my Logcat when I run the app. I don't know what the problem is with it.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.agora.TractFragment/com.agora.TractFragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 02-17 16:22:28.317: E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment E/AndroidRuntime(819):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at com.agora.TractFragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     ... 11 more
 E/AndroidRuntime(819): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.android.listfragment.ListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     ... 21 more
 E/AndroidRuntime(819): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.listfragment.ListFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.agora.TractFragment-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.agora.TractFragment-1, /system/lib]]
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
 E/AndroidRuntime(819):     ... 24 more
```

Thanks!!!!

---

```
 activity_main:


    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:background="#5f5951"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" >  

    <fragment  
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"  
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"  
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"  
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        class="com.android.listfragment.ListFragment" >  
    </fragment>  

    <FrameLayout  
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"  
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:layout_weight="2" >  
    </FrameLayout>
```

```
MainActivity.java:

package com.agora.TractFragment;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.app.FragmentManager;  
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;  
import android.os.Bundle;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  
ListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
}  

@Override  
public void onRssItemSelected(String link) 
{  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();  

DoYouKnow_Fragment layout1; //Fragment 1  
Ten_Reasons_Fragment layout2; //Fragment 2  
//Layout3 layout3; //Fragment 3  
//Layout4 layout4; //Fragment 4  

if (link.equals("layout1")) {  
layout1 = new DoYouKnow_Fragment ();  
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, layout1);  
fragmentTransaction.commit();  
} else if (link.equals("layout2")) {  
layout2 = new Ten_Reasons_Fragment();  
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, layout2);  
fragmentTransaction.commit();  
//} else if (link.equals("layout3")) {  
//layout3 = new Layout3();  
//fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, layout3);  
//fragmentTransaction.commit();  
//} else if (link.equals("layout4")) {  
//layout4 = new Layout4();  
//fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.detailFragment, layout4);  
//fragmentTransaction.commit();  
}  
}  
}
```

Comment: Can you share your XML code?

Comment: Do you have a "com.android.listfragment.ListFragment" in your codebase?  Is it surviving into the APK?  Are any related error messages appearing in logcat during a clean application install?

Comment: It looks like it's an XML error, probably syntax, which is why the class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: It is definitely something with the XML file. I just posted the XML code and Main activity with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout XML has

```
<fragment  
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"  
    android:layout_width="0dp"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_weight="1"  
    class="com.android.listfragment.ListFragment" >  
</fragment>
```

which refers to the class `com.android.listfragment.ListFragment` that does not exist. That's what's causing the exception.

In the code you don't seem to be using this fragment for anything. You can probably remove the `fragment` from the layout XML altogether.